# Loki returns data for last 11 minutes but now for 12

Tags: logging, grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

I have loki running in container together with grafana and promtail.
My docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3"

networks:
  loki:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config: 
        - subnet: 192.180.2.0/24

services:
  loki:
    image: grafana/loki:2.8.6
    container_name: loki
    volumes:
      - ./loki-config.yaml:/etc/loki/loki-config.yaml
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /data:/tmp
    command: -config.file=/etc/loki/loki-config.yaml
    ports:
      - "3100:3100"
    networks:
      - loki
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: 1m
        max-file: "3"
        tag: "common.logging.loki.docker"

  promtail:
    image: grafana/promtail:2.4.2
    container_name: promtail
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro 
      - /var/log:/var/log
      - ./promtail-local-config.yaml:/etc/promtail/config.yaml:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    command: -config.file=/etc/promtail/config.yaml
    networks:
      - loki
    ports:
      - "1514:1514/tcp"
      - "9080:9080/tcp"
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: 1m
        max-file: "3"
        tag: "common.logging.promtail.docker"

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:10.2.0
    container_name: grafana
    restart: always
    environment:
      - GF_DATAPROXY_TIMEOUT=1200
      - GF_DATAPROXY_KEEP_ALIVE_SECONDS=300
      - GF_LOG_LEVEL=debug
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - loki
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /opt/grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
      - /opt/grafana_etc:/etc/grafana
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: 1m
        max-file: "3"
        tag: "common.logging.grafana.docker"
```

```
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v12
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h

common:
  path_prefix: /tmp/loki
  storage:
    filesystem:
      chunks_directory: /tmp/loki/chunks
      rules_directory: /tmp/loki/rules

  replication_factor: 1
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory

limits_config:
  split_queries_by_interval: 15m
  max_entries_limit_per_query: 15000

query_range:
  # make queries more cache-able by aligning them with their step intervals
  align_queries_with_step: true
  max_retries: 5
  parallelise_shardable_queries: true
  cache_results: true


ruler:
  storage:
    type: local
    local:
      directory: /tmp/rules
```

I'm able to query logs. I run a first query to get logs for last 5 minutes. I get nice resposne with 4200 log lines processed in .2s [Quiery inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiENf.png) I have gotten responses for 6 minutes, 7 minutes sometimes 11 and 12 when there was not so much logs yet incoming. But going further the query goes on for some time and then I get Error: **net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)** What could be a problem?

Comment: What do you mean "What could be a problem?"? You have a timeout: Loki takes more time to process and respond with all the data you requested, than Grafana is willing to wait.

Comment: I mean do you know why I have this problem? The thing is there is not as much data so that it should tak so much time. Say there is 5Mb and it takes 0.2s to respond then I ask for 6Mb and it times out...

Comment: Try changing http timeout option in the data source settings. Also, check Loki directly if your queries for different ranges produce result in same behaviour.